# ld: library not found for -lSystem

Tags: eclipse, ld, gfortran

I recently installed gfortran and tried to run a code. However, I received a note

> ld: library not found for -lSystem
> collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Does anyone know how to resolve this issue?

Comment: Which OS? Did you search the site, there are a lot of similar questions.